# how to compute the average price of each column in purchase order lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I want to add a field that will compute the average cost price from vendors line in product. In the template, I got the first line's price works, but if I add a new vendor I get a line error

I added a computed field to product. The template form to get the price from vendors.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('seller_ids.price')
def av_price(self):
    for rec in self:
        avg_price_list = [rec.seller_ids.price]
        avg_price_list= [float(x) for x in avg_price_list]
        try:
            rec.av_price = float(sum(avg_price_list) / len(avg_price_list))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            if rec.av_price == float("inf") or self.av_price == float("-inf"):
                return float('nan')  # or x or return whatever makes sense
        pass
av_price = fields.Float(string="av price",  required=False, compute=av_price )
```

this the log

```
 File "/home/autoparts/Developments/odoo11/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4371, in ensure_one
raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self)
 ValueError: Expected singleton: product.supplierinfo(<odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f0004af1ee8>, <odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f0004af1c78>)
```

Comment: `self.av_price == float(“-inf”)` Typo?

Comment: may it's not the proplem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is in `[rec.seller_ids.price]`. `seller_ids` will be a recordset with 2 entries, when you add the second one. You can't call attributes/fields on such recordsets directly, but only on singletons (recordsets with exactly one record).

So your method should be more like this one:

```py
@api.depends('seller_ids.price')
def av_price(self):
    for rec in self:
        price_list = [s.price for s in rec.seller_ids]
        if price_list:
            rec.av_price = sum(price_list) / len(price_list)
        else:
            rec.av_price = -1  # can make sense or 0
```

IMO you should rename the field in `avg_price`, because it's is more common to abbreviate average into `avg`. And try to stick to Odoo's guidelines and rename the method to `compute_avg_price` or `compute_av_price`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get a field value from a `record set` using dot notation which will ends with:

> ValueError: Expected singleton

If you follow the guidelines about [Basic fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#basic-fields) and [Computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields). your method may look like the following:

```
@api.depends('seller_ids.price')
def _compute_av_price(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.seller_ids:
            rec.av_price = sum(seller.price for seller in rec.seller_ids) / len(rec.seller_ids)


av_price = fields.Float(string="av price", compute=_compute_av_price)
```

> required – whether the value of the field is required (boolean, by default False)